Encoding electron-phonon interactions in a quantum computer
I am trying to encode superposition of coherent-like states, that represent electron-phonon couplings on a chain, in a quantum computer.
Specifically, I would like to (approximately) generate states like:
$$ \displaystyle |\Psi \rangle = \frac{e^{-\alpha^2/2}}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{i=1}^{N} e^{-\alpha b_i^{\dagger}} c_i^{\dagger}  |\text{vac}\rangle$$.
where $c_i^{\dagger},b_i^{\dagger}$ are the fermionic and bosonic creation operators respectively.
I was thinking maybe one can use Jordan-wigner transformation to encode the electronic part. But how would one go about dealing the bosons and then coupling them?
